# Localized routing in CakePHP: How to redirect to default language

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, routes

Since 2012, [this post](http://colorblindprogramming.com/multiple-languages-in-a-cakephp-2-application-in-5-steps) appears to be the most definitive resource on how to do localized routes in CakePHP (code copied below).

It works great, with one exception: it doesn't redirect requests that are missing the language prefix. For example, http://example.com will show the same content as http://example.com/eng (if English is the default language). And similarly, if it's not the homepage: http://example.com/foo/bar/ => http://example.com/eng/foo/bar. There is some mention of this problem in the comments, but no conclusive solution, which is what I'm looking for.

Code.

```
// Step 1: app/Config/routes.php
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
                  array(),
                  array('language' => 'eng|fra'));

Router::connect('/:language/:controller',
                  array('action' => 'index'),
                  array('language' => 'eng|fra'));  

Router::connect('/:language',
                  array('controller' => 'welcome', 'action' => 'index'),
                  array('language' => 'eng|fra'));

//Step 2: app/Config/core.php
Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');

//Step 3: create app/View/Helper/MyHtmlHelper.php
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {
    public function url($url = null, $full = false) {
        if(!isset($url['language']) && isset($this->params['language'])) {
          $url['language'] = $this->params['language'];
        }
        return parent::url($url, $full);
   }
}

//Step 4: app/Controller/AppController.php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array('Cookie','Session');
    //set an alias for the newly created helper: Html<->MyHtml
    public $helpers = array('Html' => array('className' => 'MyHtml'));

    public function beforeFilter() {
          $this->_setLanguage();
        }

    private function _setLanguage() {
    //if the cookie was previously set, and Config.language has not been set
    //write the Config.language with the value from the Cookie
        if ($this->Cookie->read('lang') && !$this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->Cookie->read('lang'));
        } 
        //if the user clicked the language URL 
        else if (   isset($this->params['language']) && 
        ($this->params['language'] !=  $this->Session->read('Config.language'))
                ) {
            //then update the value in Session and the one in Cookie
            $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->params['language']);
            $this->Cookie->write('lang', $this->params['language'], false, '20 days');
        }
    }

    //override redirect
    public function redirect( $url, $status = NULL, $exit = true ) {
        if (!isset($url['language']) && $this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
            $url['language'] = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
        }
        parent::redirect($url,$status,$exit);
    }
}

//add the links to the languages:
//Step 5: app/View/...
echo $this->Html->link('English', array('language'=>'eng')); 
echo $this->Html->link('Français', array('language'=>'fra'));
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried the suggestion by user221931, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I added to my routes:

```
/* Add default language param */
Router::redirect('/:controller/:action/*', 
                    array('language' => 'fra'), 
                    array('persist' => false) );
Router::redirect('/:controller/', 
                    array('language' => 'fra'), 
                    array('persist' => false) );
Router::redirect('/', 
                    array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display', 'language' => 'fra', 'home'), 
                    array('persist' => false) );
```

It seems to have no effect. The following URLs are *not* redirected: http:example.com/, http://example.com/controller/, http://example.com/controller/action/

**UPDATE 2**
As requested, here is my *complete* routes file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

#http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html
Router::parseExtensions('json');

/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));


/**
 * LOCALIZED URLs
 * See: http://colorblindprogramming.com/multiple-languages-in-a-cakephp-2-application-in-5-steps
 */
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
                       array(),
                       array('language' => 'eng|fra'));

Router::connect('/:language/:controller',
                   array('action' => 'index'),
                   array('language' => 'eng|fra')); 

Router::connect('/:language',
                   array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
                   array('language' => 'eng|fra'));

# prevent routing conflicts with plugins...
# http://www.omaroid.com/cakephp-locale-language-routing/
// make an array of loaded plugins
$loaded = CakePlugin::loaded();
array_walk($loaded, function(&$item,$key){
    $item = Inflector::underscore($item);
});
$loaded = implode('|', $loaded);

Router::connect('/:language/:plugin/:controller/:action/*', 
                    array(), 
                    array('language' => 'eng|fra','plugin' => "($loaded)"));

/* HIDE /index */
//Router::connect('/:controller/', array('action'=>'index') );
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/', array('action'=>'index') );

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You added the very specific language routing (if first part of url path is `eng` or `fra`) but didn't remove the default routing (`Router::connect('/:controller/:action/*'`) so if these two words are not found the more generic route of `/:controller/:action/*` will match.

You can do any of the next three things:

1. Remove the default routes which will make `/:controller/:action/*` and `/:controller/*` unroutable and noone will be able to form urls that will access the content without the language in there.
2. Add hardcoded `routes` that redirect to `eng` i.e. `/users` -> `/eng/users`, `/posts/` -> `/eng/posts`, etc). This might seem as a lot of work, but while pattern match is ok for development, hardcoding dramatically improves the speed of routing so you'll probably need to go that way some point in the future. The added advantage of it is that you can add a `persist` rule that will make the browser remember the redirect and not hit the server anymore.
3. Add code in your `AppController` that will check to see if language is included in the path and if not try to guess the users language from the browser settings so to redirect to the most appropriate url or the default.

Number 1 is the easiest, cleanest and fastest but might not be appropriate if you have controllers that don't need to have language in front.

Number 2 doesn't leave you with a choice on what language you redirect to as it will be hardcoded. Depending on the app it might be perfectly ok.

Number 3 is the most elegant solution from UX perspective but is causing some slight overhead in each page load (by checking the language).

Comment: Option #2 would be fine. I don't mind having one default language hard coded for situations when it's missing in the url. Can you show me how to do that? I read the docs for Cakes Router::redirect but couldn't figure out how to use it in this context.

Comment: I can't test this now but I think this `Router::redirect('/:controller/:action/*', array('language' => 'eng'), array('persist' => false));` will work. If it does, changing `persist` to `true` will make the browser keep the redirect in its cache and not hit the server at all, so try it only if it works first if you don't want to clear the cache all the time.

Comment: I tried your snippet but it doesn't seem to work. I've updated the question above.

Comment: I see, I still can't try it cause I'm at a computer without even php. You can redirect to a fixed url for sure `Router::redirect('/', '/fra/', array('persist' => false) );`, if you can't even do that then something else must be wrong.

Comment: Ok. I figured out one problem. I still had the two default `::connect` rules (one for pages, and one for "/"). If I remove those, the redirects start working, but not correctly. It seems to mix up the language/controller/action params.

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding which of my original code should stay or be replaced by your code.

Comment: Would you consider submitting your suggestion as an answer with a bit of clarification as to what should replace what?

Comment: Please add your complete routes and exact cake version and I will give it a try :)

Comment: Cool! I added the complete routes.php file under Update 2 above. I'm using CakePHP v2.5.6. Bounty initiated!

Comment: I finally got some time to try it out. It seems my second suggestion is wrong because a route must either match a pattern with `connect` or a string (not a pattern as I wrongly remembered) with `redirect`. It would work if you could manually redirect all your routes (write multiple redirects from i.e. `/users` -> `/eng/users`, `/posts/` -> `/eng/posts`, etc). I will update my post for completeness.

Comment: Is your #3 basically what @bancer proposed below? Or did you have something different in mind?

Comment: If I would go that way I'd prefer checking the language of the browser and redirect accordingly, but it's pretty much the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty simple to do from AppController.php:

```
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'eng';
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if (empty($this->params['language'])) {
        $this->redirect(array('language' => self::DEFAULT_LANGUAGE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems to work for normal controller/action URLs (`http://example.com/con/act/`), but it breaks when I try to hit the homepage (`http://example.com`). It redirects to `http://example.com/pages/language:fra`. I think it has to do with the default `Router::connect`s for the homepage and/or pages.

Comment: I removed `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));` and now the homepage seems to work as expected. All that remains is that my language toggle buttons still point to the incorrect URL (above), but it's only an issue on the views controlled by pages controller. Any idea why?

Comment: Seems like it MUST be an issue with MyHtmlHelper?

Comment: In fact, you do not need MyHtmlHelper. You can override url() in AppHelper. If HtmlHelper generates URL like http://example.com/pages/language:fra that means that the problem is related to a missing or not applied route in routes.php.

Comment: isn't overriding url() what MyHtmlHelper is doing? Is there an advantage to doing it in AppHelper? Also, do you have any advice about which route would be missing to cause that?